# Reporting services visibility cells use groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have a problem with Reporting services 2012.

I have a tablix with a cascade groups organizations (childrens recursively depending on the same parent).

(Parent, Children, Children of children, etc)

I want to hide the children group based on an expression, but when I do this the full row hides. The expression that I use is:

```
=IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!ListaTipoIncidencias.Value,"/"),CType(Fields!IDINCIDENCIATIPO.Value, GUID).ToString)>0, False, True)
```

For aclaration, "ListaTipoIncidencias" is a parameter multivalued.

I need to hide the children group only, not the full row. Check the images below

This is the original table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZHmn.png

This is what happens when the children row group is hidde, the report hide the row instead of hide only the children group (check the red mark on this picture)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1epru.png

How i can do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understand your answer. What is "your scope"? I want hide rows of last group.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression can also check for the level of the hierarchy recursion like the sample code below

```
=IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!ListaTipoIncidencias.Value,"/"),CType(Fields!IDINCIDENCIATIPO.Value, GUID).ToString)>0 AND Level("your scope")<2, False, True)
```